# correct usage with at and as

Tags: grammar, british-english

> My best friend committed suicide because he was being bullied for being "blind" **at his high school** shortly after this song was released. He stated this song and lyrics gave him comfort and solitude to live his life. In closing, the taunting, harassment, and degrading finally broke him down mentally and emotionally and he took his life at 17  years old, **as he had his entire life in front of him.**

I'm just curious about this sentence. The use of "at" & "as" which appear wrong. In the sense, he's being bullied for being blind at highschool and committed suicide because he had his whole life in front of him.

If you add **during** his highschool years to the first example and just to the second it works, but what is the grammatical error here concerning at and as?

Answer (score 2):

I would amend the first sentence to:

> My best friend committed suicide because he was being bullied **at his high school for being "blind"** shortly after this song was released.

This makes it clear that he was being bullied for being "blind" in general, which I'm sure is the case, rather than being bullied for being "blind" **only** at his high school.

The last sentence makes no sense, as it makes it sound like he took his life **because** he had his whole life ahead of him.

This should probably be something like:

> In closing, the taunting, harassment, and degrading finally broke him down mentally and emotionally and he took his life at 17 years old, despite having his entire life in front of him.

Or something more emotionally expressive would be:

> In closing, the taunting, harassment, and degrading finally broke him down mentally and emotionally and he took his life at 17 years old - and he had his entire life in front of him!